# Enforce rebase before each commit (git)

Tags: git, git-config

I have to mention I'm new to git before you judge me for asking (maybe) stupid question. I'm working in an environment where we have a lot of branches and one is considered the mainline. Because we have different teams working on the project, we configured jenkins to build and run tests after every commit on any branch. But here comes the problem, people commit on their branch without rebasing with the mainline so the tests fail sometimes because modifications were pushed for the mentioned tests in the mainline and people don't have the modifications on their branch. Is there any way I could configure git to reject any commit if it's not rebased with the mainline branch?

**UPDATE:**

I'm currently trying something like (pre-commit hook):

```
#!/bin/sh

if git rev-list --left-right --count mainbranch...@ | cut -f1 > 0
then
    exi1
fi
```

but the if always returns true. The command `git rev-list --left-right --count mainbranch...@ | cut -f1 > 0` should return (and it does) the number of commits that my mainbranch is ahead (if > 0 then I need to rebase).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, you don't necessarily have to rebase a branch to bring it up to date; you could also merge, which might be a simpler option.  Yes, you can probably write a hook to check for this, but if you just use a tool like GitHub which has pull requests you can loosely enforce that a feature branch is up to date with its destination.

Comment: We are using TFS. I'll search if there's a guide to accomplish the enforce you mentioned. Now, I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: Can someone help me with a hook to enforce rebase before commit?

Comment: I dont want to not answer the question, but i really think your problem is not about rebasing.

I think your actual problem is that, from what I understand, your tests are not in the same branch or not in the same repository as the code under test.

You said « we configured jenkins to build and run tests after every commit on any branch» : that's perfect.

But, each branch should have a version of those tests, and Jenkins should be configured to run the tests that are in the branch, not always the tests that are in the mainline branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a simple shell-script issue. Your command

```
if git rev-list --left-right --count mainbranch...@ | cut -f1 > 0
```

is interpreted as "run `git rev-list`, pipe it to `cut`, and write the output to a file named `0`", which will always succeed.

What you want is "run `git rev-list`, pipe it to `cut`, and compare the result to the number `0`":

```
if [[ "$(git rev-list --left-right --count mainbranch...@ | cut -f1)" > 0 ]]
```